# Taxis at Tokyo Haneda Airport

Tags: japan, airport-transfer, taxis, tokyo, hnd

I'll be flying into Tokyo Haneda at 10:25pm on a Sunday and rather than try to figure out the public transit system that late in the day when I'm already probably going to be exhausted I was thinking I'd prefer to just take a taxi to the hotel. My question is...  do taxis loiter around at the airport, waiting for passengers, as they do in the USA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](https://tokyo-haneda.com/en/access/taxi/index.html), of course there are.  Depending on where you're going, it may cost you up to ¥10,000 (~US$100) if you board after midnight.

Answer (score 6):

If you're wanting to save a little money on extortionate Tokyo taxi fees there is a direct monorail service from Haneda Airport to Hamamatsucho, cutting the distance required by taxi significantly. Outside Hamamatsucho (the main 'departing to Haneda' station) are a huge fleet of taxis. The monorail is fast and the station is inside the terminal.

Comment: Just beware that the last weekday service departs at 0:10, although clearing Customs etc in an hour and half should not be a problem.  Also, depending on where you're going, the Keikyu railway (also within terminal) might get you closer to your destination.  It's nowhere near as fun though ;)

Comment: True, I arrived around 11pm on an Emirates flight recently and made it with about 10 minutes to spare. Just make sure to not dawdle as you leave :)

Comment: I had considered that option for a flight but decided I wouldn't be able to get to suburban Tokyo so chose another flight. Good call on taking the monorail to central Tokyo and then a taxi though... that way even if trains shutdown you can still get place, but save the cost of the trip into Tokyo.